# Python PIL: open many files and load them into memory

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a dataset containing 3000 images in train and 6000 images in test. It's 320x320 rgb png files. I thought that I can load this entire dataset into memory (since it's just 100mb), but then I try to do that I'm getting "[Errno 24] Too many open files: ..." error. Code of loading looks like that:

```
train_images = []
for index, row in dataset_p_train.iterrows():
    path = data_path / row.img_path
    train_images.append(Image.open(path))
```

I know that I'm opening 9000 files and not closing them which isn't a good practice, but unfortunately for my classificator I heavily rely on PIL `img.getcolors()` method, so I really want to store that dataset in memory as list of PIL images and not as a numpy array of 3000x320x320x3 uint8 to avoid casting them into PIL image each time I need colors of image.

So, what should I do? Somehow increase limit of opened files? Or there is a way to make PIL images reside entirely in memory without being "opened" from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.open` is lazy. It will not load the data until you try to do something with it.

You can call the image's [`load` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.load) to explicitly load the file contents. This will also close the file, unless the image has multiple frames (for example, an animated GIF).

See [File Handling in Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/open_files.html#file-handling) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

every time you open an image using PIL it requires the variable storing the image to be closed otherwise it just opens up a new memory location and changes the location the variable points to in memory, open() is normally used for small data sets that would become idle and can be collected by garbage collection but on larger data sets it doesnt become idle often and wont close them in time

to fix this use the code

```
with Image.open(path) as img:
```

to prevent the problems caused by open() and load() by manually closing any loaded images in memory as PIL doesnt often do this automatically

Comment: almost nothing that you said is technically accurate. your suggestion for opening is also creating nesting problem if they have multiple files to open.  Open has nothing to do with the file size being big or small.  Garbage collection has nothing to do with them becoming idle or not.  It has to do with reference counting.  If you call open you have to make sure you call close it wont be done for you.  Using the `with... as` idiom the lifetime manager takes care of that for you if supported by the API.   IDLENESS has nothing do with anything here.